# NULL vs nullptr (Why was it replaced?)

Tags: c++, pointers, null, nullptr

I know that in C++ `0x` or `NULL` was replaced by `nullptr` in pointer-based applications.  I'm just curious of the exact reason why they made this replacement?

In what scenario is using `nullptr` over `NULL` beneficial when dealing with pointers?

Comment: @BryanChen it's not.  I don't want to know WHAT a nullptr is...I want to know why it was implemented and what the benefit is if you read the question correctly

Comment: read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1283623/642626)

Comment: @BryanChen a couple of keywords in that are unfamiliar to me so that answer is unreadable....nevertheless, not a duplicate question just simply a question within the same topic with a potentially useful answer

Comment: maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19014644/642626) is easier to understand

Answer (score 478, accepted):

`nullptr` has type `std::nullptr_t`.  It's implicitly convertible to any pointer type.  Thus, it'll match `std::nullptr_t` or pointer types in overload resolution, but not other types such as `int`.

`0` (aka. C's NULL bridged over into C++) could cause ambiguity in overloaded function resolution, among other things:

```
f(int);
f(foo *);
```

(Thanks to Caleth pointing this out in the comments.)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I have no idea how to respond to this other than the fact that I knew what I was asking and this was the easiest to understand explanation.

Comment: @Riptyde4: Shafik's answer is IMHO the most comprehensive. The quote there includes both the "ambigious overload" of this answer and the "templated argument type problem" of my answer, plus it's a nice reference. This answer is just a small part of the reasons.

Comment: but we can always specify the type using typecast operator like f( (int) NULL ) or f((foo*) NULL ) as an alternative to resolve ambiguity... correct ?

Comment: FWIW, I agree w/ Cheers that Shafik's answer is more comprehensive.  In fact, I upvoted it some time ago.

Comment: Arjun: Yes, a cast can resolve the ambiguity, although I suppose there are still cases it cannot replace such as std::nullptr_t as an overload.  Also, I don't think I'd use (int)NULL since semantically NULL is supposed to be pointer and may be actually be defined as nullptr.  You're not guaranteed to get a 0 when to cast nullptr to int.  Perhaps (int)0?

Comment: Nitpick: the type of `nullptr` is `std::nullptr_t`, which is not a pointer type. `nullptr` implicitly converts to any pointer type, and importantly *does not* convert to any integer type.

Comment: Thanks, Caleth.  You are correct.  I've tweaked my wording accordingly.

Comment: It's short, clear, efficient, best answer in my opinion too. Thanks.

Answer (score 99):

You can find a good explanation of why it was replaced by reading [A name for the null pointer: nullptr](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2431.pdf), to quote the paper:

> This problem falls into the following categories:
>
> - Improve support for library building, by providing a way for users to write less ambiguous code, so that over time library writers will not need to worry about overloading on integral and pointer types.
> - Improve support for generic programming, by making it easier to express both integer 0 and nullptr unambiguously.
> - Make C++ easier to teach and learn.

Answer (score 67):

Here is [Bjarne Stroustrup's wordings,](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null)

> In C++, the definition of NULL is 0, so there is only an aesthetic difference. I prefer to avoid macros, so I use 0. Another problem with NULL is that people sometimes mistakenly believe that it is different from 0 and/or not an integer. In pre-standard code, NULL was/is sometimes defined to something unsuitable and therefore had/has to be avoided. That's less common these days.
>
> If you have to name the null pointer, call it nullptr; that's what
>   it's called in C++11. Then, "nullptr" will be a keyword.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, only gives a source for the name...

Comment: @Quirliom: I think that's the reason for the new keyword **nullptr** in C++11

Comment: @Sinkingpoint is right. This is part way to being an answer because it explains one of the problems with `NULL`, but it doesn't explain how `nullptr` avoids that problem or why `nullptr` was actually introduced (which are the questions that the OP is actually asking).

Comment: ok; thanks; but I'm sorry because I answered this question a rather long time ago; now I couldn't remember things on it.!

Answer (score 18):

One reason: the literal `0` has a bad tendency to acquire the type `int`, e.g. in perfect argument forwarding or more in general as argument with templated type.

Another reason: readability and clarity of code.

Comment: I agree but: The origin question is about the difference of NULL and nullptr ;-)

Comment: @hrfmobile: `NULL` is a macro that could be and usually was defined as literal `0` (possibly with a type suffix). With current g++, version 9.2, it's instead defined as the intrinsic `__null`. With current Visual C++, 2019, it's defined as plain `0`.

Thus, the first reason I gave applies *when* `NULL` is defined as a literal.

The second reason always applies, but is more subjective. However, most people agree that all uppercase is an eyesore, shouting. Which is a main reason why that naming convention is used for macros.

Comment: Well, for the type of `NULL`, the C++ standard could have added `std::nullptr_t` without adding `nullptr`, and define `#define NULL  ((std::nullptr_t) 0)`, similar to what POSIX does in C:  `#define NULL  ((void *) 0)`.  You wouldn't need a new keyword.

Comment: @alx I guess the use of a keyword precludes the all-too-prevalent `#undef NULL / #define NULL <something else I think is even better than the standard>` that can trip up anyone looking at `NULL` in the code thinking it means one thing when it means something else.  After all, what's wrong with `#define true ((bool)1)`?