# Tree implementation in C++: Cannot convert Node to Node*

Tags: c++, nodes

My error is regarding the last two assignment statements in main. I am trying to create a basic tree by having each node point to 2 other nodes: left and right. I have also tried adding * in front of n1, n2, and n3 when creating them, but that did not work either...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Node{

    public:
    string value;
    Node *left, *right;

    public:
    Node(string s, Node *l, Node *r){
        value = s;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
    void display(){
        cout << value << left->value << right->value;
    }

};
int main(){

    Node n1("this", NULL,NULL);
    Node n2("is", NULL, NULL);
    Node n3("next", NULL, NULL);
    n1.left = n2;
    n1.right = n3;

    n1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried  n1.left = &n2;

Comment: @ivanw cool that worked! Thank you! Can you please tell me what the difference is between * and &? I thought both of them made them pointers or referred the to memory location...

Comment: & returns address of while * deferences or declares a pointer.

Comment: Also, no need to mention `public` twice. Just minor things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int main(){

    Node n1("this", NULL,NULL);
    Node n2("is", NULL, NULL);
    Node n3("next", NULL, NULL);
    n1.left = &n2;
    n1.right = &n3;

    n1.display();
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create nodes like:

```
Node n1("this", NULL,NULL);
```

you create them on stack, so `n1` is an object. `n1.left` is a pointer, so you have to assign a pointer to it too. In order to get a pointer to an object, you have to use the `&`operator, like:

```
n1.left = &n2;
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Node n1("this", NULL,NULL);
> Node n2("is", NULL, NULL);
> Node n3("next", NULL, NULL);
>
> n1.left = n2;
> n1.right = n3;
> ```

`left` and `right` are **pointers** to Node instances (in fact, you defined them as `Node *left`, `Node *right`).

So you have to take the address of n2 and n3 to do the assignments:

```
n1.left = &n2;
n1.right = &n3;
```

Moreover, note that in C++11/14, you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Oh okay. Is it because NULL just refers to the value of something but nullptr actually means that it is pointing to nothing? UPDATE: I just tried doing nullptr but it is saying that 'nullptr" was not declared in that scope...

Comment: Please read _"[NULL vs nullptr (Why was it replaced?)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20509734/1629821)"_ .