# why does the runner pointer below not change to null?

Tags: c++, pointers

why does the runner pointer not changed to null?

```
Node* runner = head->next;
Node* reversedList = head;
reversedList->next = nullptr;
```

but in the following, it does change to null

```
Node* reversedList = head;
reversedList->next = nullptr;
Node* runner = head->next;
```

Comment: This should be tagged C++ since `nullptr` doesn't exist in C.

Comment: Your question is incomplete define the structure you are using

Comment: structure is just simple linkedlist node with a pointer to next and an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you issue the following statement

```
Node* runner = head->next;
```

'runner' points to address memory pointed by 'next' (let's say it is address 0x6543).

(head->next) ------> content <----(runner)

The following two lines:

```
Node* reversedList = head;

reversedList->next = nullptr;
```

So, 'next' points to NULL now, but 'runner' still points to the address previously pointed by 'next', i.e., 0x6543.

(head->next) --> NULL | content <-------- (runner)

The second example works because first you make head->next points to NULL then you make 'runner' points to head->next, that now is NULL. As 'head' and 'reversedList' both points to same address the second example -- without reversedList -- would be:

```
head->next = nullptr; 

Node* runner = head->next;
```

Comment: shouldn't this line from the snippet that doesn't change the runner pointer to nullptr change the value in its address to null:  reversedList->next = nullptr;  thus runner should have been changed to nullptr? or maybe the question should be, why doesn't it change the value in that address to nullptr?

Comment: Nope. nullptr is dealing with pointers to  memory addresses, not the content of those addresses. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20509811

Comment: An analogy would be: you take two pieces of paper and write the same telephone number on both. Then you tear one paper (set to nullptr). You still have the other piece of paper intact -- with the telephone number on it --, as well as it doesn't discard the telephone. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the first one you store the pointers `head` and `head->next` in `reversedList` and `runner` respectively. Then you change `reversedList->next` to be `nullptr`, but `runner` was a copy of `head-next` not a reference to the pointer itself. Therefore it didn't change.

But in the second one you made `reversedList->next` `nullptr` and then made a copy of the next pointer (which you just made `nullptr`) therefore the copy is a `nullptr`