# Can I use nullptr as a Linux system call parameter?

Tags: c++, c, linux, c++11, system-calls

I'm developing a user space application on Raspbian in C++11.
ReSharper++ advises me to use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` in the following system call:

```
auto ret = timerfd_settime(this->_timer_fd, 0, &timeout, NULL);
assert(0 == ret);
```

I think that I should stay with `NULL` because this library is dedicated for system programming in C.

What is the best practice in this situation?

Comment: `NULL` and `nullptr` are both valid null pointer constants in C++; it's just that `nullptr` is more type-safe in certain situations. If you have an "extern C" C linkage function that takes a pointer parameter (which may be null), it's perfectly fine to pass it `nullptr`.

Comment: Thanks, that is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stay with nullptr because the intention is more clear.

There is a implicit conversion of nullptr to pointer for any type so you are definitely safe.

cppreference.com:

> The keyword nullptr denotes the pointer literal. It is a prvalue of
>   type std::nullptr_t. There exist implicit conversions from nullptr to
>   null pointer value of any pointer type and any pointer to member type.

Answer (score 2):

Both `NULL` and `nullptr` will work fine. However, since this is syspro in C, I would go with `NULL`, because it's what I see more often (if not always) in that field.

If you check the [reference](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) of your system call, you will see that everywhere `NULL` is mentioned, not `nullptr`, something which you should expect (if not make sure you 'll read the following answer).

Check also [NULL vs nullptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509734/null-vs-nullptr-why-was-it-replaced).