# C++: is it possible to create template function returning null?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function that can return different types.

```
template <class typ>
typ GetRespVal_byField(const std::string & _fname){
for (pqxx::result::const_iterator row = m_result.begin();
     row != m_result.end();
     ++row)
    {
        if (!row[_fname].is_null())
            return row[_fname].as<typ>();
        else
            return NULL; //this is what i want 

    }
}
```

Is it a correct implementation?

Comment: it gets compiled but i am not sure if it is a correct way to do it ..

Comment: The only one who can determine if it is a "correct way to do it" is you. Because only you could possibly know what is the correct behavior for your own code.

Comment: In c++0x and forward you may want to consider the `nullptr` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509734/null-vs-nullptr-why-was-it-replaced.

Answer (score 3):

As far as `typ` can take `NULL` value (or if a `typ`object can be constructed from a `NULL`value), yes, you can. If `type` is a pointer or an `int` for instance.

You can even return `foo_bar`....if `foo_bar` is a valid `typ`value, it will work....

Template resolution is done upon compilation, so, as YSC commented, if it compiles, then yes, it's allowed in term of type checking (now, the fact that code compile does not necessarily mean it will work at runtime, but, for your specific question, it's good enough)....

Comment: That's not quite true. Compilers are free to compile code with undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Right, but it won't compile if types are incompatible. Updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to create template function returning null?

Generally, yes, of course. Why shouldn't a template function be able to do that?

However...

> Is it a correct implementation?

This depends on your definition of "correct" :)

For example, if you try to instantiate the function with `std::string` for `typ`, then returning `NULL` invokes undefined behaviour (because you would try to construct a `std::string` from a null pointer). Undefined behaviour is usually considered a very incorrect thing.

Consider [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) as an alternative to represent the non-existence of something. It's more generic than `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but might not always be a good idea. For example, if `typ` is a `string`, then your code would compile, because NULL would be interpreted as `char *` from which to implicitly construct a string. However, the code would fail at runtime when the `else` branch is hit, because trying to construct a string from NULL is undefined behavior that would almost certainly lead to an access violation.

So I would suggest at least two improvements to your code.

1. Use type traits in combination with a `static_assert` to assure that `typ` is a pointer type. Add this to your template function:

   ```
   static_assert(is_pointer<typ>::value, "<typ> must be a pointer type");
   ```

   This rules out types that are not pointers, but are constructible from a pointer, and additionally makes the error message more clear to the user.
2. Return `nullptr` rather than `NULL` - mostly to make the intention more explicit, but also to avoid hypothetical scenarios when a conversion to integral type would be a bad thing (unlike `NULL`, `nullptr` is not implicitly converted to integral types).

Answer (score 1):

More generally, compiling a template doesn't do much. Microsoft only recently [abandoned something](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/09/25/rejuvenating-the-microsoft-c-c-compiler.aspx) one could roughly call a text replacement implementation for templates:

> The method chosen to implement this [templates, in the old compiler] was to do some minimal parsing of
>   a template and then capture the whole template as a string of tokens
>   (this is very similar to how macros are handled in the compiler). **Later, when a template is instantiated,** that token stream would be replayed through the parser and template arguments would be replaced.

The reason this was abandoned is that it is not quite sufficient to implement templates correctly. But a template in C++ is still very much a *template*  in the semantic sense, which is why the the usual method to compile template using code involves having the template source available.

This is a striking contrast to C# which compiles standalone templates in the strict sense (to IL, of course).

*Instantiating* a template does more:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

// this works;
template<typename T> T f(T t)
{
    return cout;
}       

// this doesn't 
// double  d = f(1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a type trait class which would define a NULL for any type you use. I suppose you would have problem with that - what NULL would you specify for `std::string`? You could change your function signature and return `std::pair<typ, bool>` where:

1. if non NULL value is returned, then `first` is equal to returned value and `second` to `true`.
2. if NULL value should be returned, then first is equal to default initialized typ, and `second` is `false`