# C++ template for calling functions

Tags: c++, pointers, variadic-templates

I have to call different functions in same manner:

```
VixHandle jobHandle = VIX_INVALID_HANDLE;
jobHandle = VixHost_Connect(VIX_API_VERSION, provider, host.c_str(), 0, user.c_str(), password.c_str(), 0, VIX_INVALID_HANDLE,NULL, NULL);
VixHandle result = Vix_waitJobResult(jobHandle);
```

I want to simplify source code, and use something like this:

```
template <typename FUNC, typename ... ARGS>
VixHandle VIX_CALL(FUNC fun, ARGS ... arg){
    VixHandle result = VIX_INVALID_HANDLE;
    VixHandle jobHandle = VIX_INVALID_HANDLE;
    jobHandle = fun(arg...);
    result = Vix_waitJobResult(jobHandle);
    Vix_ReleaseHandle(jobHandle);
    return result;
}
```

And make call look like:

```
VixHandle hostHandle = VIX_CALL(VixHost_Connect, VIX_API_VERSION, provider, host.c_str(), 0, user.c_str(), password.c_str(), 0, VIX_INVALID_HANDLE,NULL, NULL);
```

Obviously, my template does not work, and I am not sure how to fix it:

```
C:\Users\crashtua\Documents\CppVix\vix_api_helper.h:12: error: C2664: 'VixHandle (int,VixServiceProvider,const char *,int,const char *,const char *,VixHostOptions,VixHandle,VixEventProc (__cdecl *),void *)': cannot convert argument 10 from 'int' to 'void *'
```

And finnaly, how I can fix(or rewrite) my template to make it work as I expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the compiler interprets `NULL` as an `int` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509734/null-vs-nullptr-why-was-it-replaced) or, better, Scott Meyer's [Effective Modern C++](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do)). *You* know that the intent is a pointer, but *the compiler* doesn't. You should use [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr).

In the example below, see `make_vix_2`'s call:

```
#include <utility>
class vix_handle{};
template<class Fn, typename ...Args>
void vix_call(Fn fn, Args &&...args)
{
    vix_handle job_handle = fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

vix_handle make_vix_0(int, int, int){return vix_handle();}
vix_handle make_vix_1(float){return vix_handle();}
vix_handle make_vix_2(char *){return vix_handle();}

int main()
{
    vix_call(make_vix_0, 1, 2, 3);
    vix_call(make_vix_1, 1.0);
    vix_call(make_vix_2, nullptr);                                                                                                          
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, just read error more carefully and fixed it using nullptr. After that looked at your answer and saw same solution as I did. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @crashtua You're welcome. While we're at it, I suggest looking at my code for `std::forward` too - it's well-established practice for good reason.

Comment: Just wondering, what difference between Args &&...args and Args ...args

Comment: @crashtua Ooh, too long to answer in a comment - I really suggest you read a C++11 book. They're *universal pointers*, BTW.

Comment: Hm, I really should to read such book when will have free time:). Thanks a lot for a help, again.