# Incorrect overload resolution with value of const argument as 0

Tags: c++, constants, overloading, c++98

I have a class `B` with two overloaded functions `int Set(B *);` and `int Set(const A&);`. The class `A` expects a constructor argument `unsigned char`. When `Set` is called with a `const unsigned char` with value as `0`, it is resolved to `Set(B*)` whereas when the value passed is non-zero, it resolves to `Set(const A&)` (as per my expectation).

The overload resolution works expectedly with non-const `unsigned char` but fails with `const unsigned char` with value set as `0`. Why?

Following code illustrates the discrepancy when `Set` is called with const and non-const `unsigned char`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class A{
  char m_byteValue;
public:
  A(unsigned char c) {
    m_byteValue = c;
  }
};


class B{
  int m_a;
public:
  B(){
    m_a = 2;
  }
  int Set(B *);
  int Set(const A&);
};

int B::Set(const A& v) {
  cout << "I am in the const ref function\n";
  return 0;
}

int B::Set(B* p) {
  cout << "I am in the pointer function\n";
  return 0;
}

int main(){
  const unsigned char a = 0;
  const unsigned char b = 1;
  unsigned char c = 0;
  unsigned char d = 1;
  B var;
  var.Set(a);
  var.Set(b);
  var.Set(c);
  var.Set(d);
  return 0;
}
```

Output (as compiled by `gcc 4.9.2` c++98):
[Demo](http://ideone.com/H0P0ya) - on ideone c++ 5.1

```
I am in the pointer function // Why?
I am in the const ref function
I am in the const ref function
I am in the const ref function
```

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](http://cpp.sh/5tgd) in GCC 4.9.2

Comment: @CoryKramer: It is reproducible in c++98.

Comment: Hmm strange. Wonder if it's simply because there's essentially a `#DEFINE NULL 0` somewhere since this was preceding `nullptr`, so it thinks that `0` should be passed as a pointer (since it thinks you are passing `NULL`. This problem is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509734/null-vs-nullptr-why-was-it-replaced) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr).

Comment: Added the C++98 tag as this only shows up in that version.  I can't test C++03 to confirm its addition.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Also, reproduced in C++03.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the standards is here:

C++98 [conv.ptr]

> A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero.

C++11 [conv.ptr]

> A *null pointer constant* is an integer literal with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

`const unsigned char a = 0;` satisfies the C++98 definition of an integral constant expression. Of course `a` is not an rvalue, but it seems that an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applies and is still a better match than the user-defined conversion from `unsigned char` to `A`.

`a` is not a literal, this is what makes the behaviour different in C++11.

Comment: Great answer, better than mine.

Comment: Just as a confirmation, your answer is bang on. Passing `(unsigned char)0` to `Set` has the same behavior with C++11, C++14.

Answer (score 2):

Clang reproduces the error, but fortunately also gives you the answer during compilation:

```
overloading_incorrect.cxx:41:13: warning: expression which evaluates
to zero treated as a null pointer constant of type 'B *'
[-Wnon-literal-null-conversion] 
var.Set(a);
        ^
```

As NathanOliver mentions correctly under your post, this behavior disappears as soon as the c++11 standard is used (adding the `-std=c++11` flag to the compiler).

Comment: But why is 0 treated as null pointer? Any const value set to 0 can have this undefined behavior. Seems very dangerous.

Comment: CoryKramer gives you the answer. `NULL` is defined as `0`, so somehow `0` is ambiguous in its type.

Comment: THere is a discussion about this behavior in [DR456](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html). I did not find any followups which changed this behavior in C++11

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: explains well.