# How to remove nodes from the list

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I want my program to remove nodes and return item in `RemoveHead()` function. I am not sure what is the mistake. In `main()` function , Everything is going fine but my program is not removing `Head`and its still printing the previous list `L1`: a non empty list.

To make it more clear i am uploading my output and desired output.

This is My program:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "===== Testing Step-1 =====\n";
    cout << "Testing default constructor...\n";
    LinkedList L1;
    L1.Print(); // should be empty
    cout<<"\nTesting AddHead()...\n";
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout << i << ' ';
        L1.AddHead(i);
    }
    cout << endl;
    L1.Print();
    cout << "\nTesting IsEmpty() and RemoveHead()...\n";
    while(!L1.IsEmpty())
        cout << L1.RemoveHead()<< ' '; // should be printed in reverse
    cout << endl; 
    L1.Print(); // should be empty
}

int LinkedList::RemoveHead()
{
    if(Head==NULL)
    {
        cerr << "Error Occured. " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {       
        NodePtr temp;
        temp->Item = Head->Item;
        temp = Head;
        Head = Head->Next;
        delete temp;
    }
 //return 0; to be removed while compilation

bool LinkedList::IsEmpty()
{
  Head==NULL;
  return true;
}
void LinkedList::Print()
{

    if (Head==0)
    {
        cout << "Empty error ." ;
    }
    else
    {
        NodePtr crnt;
        crnt = Head;
        while(crnt!= NULL)
        {
            cout << crnt->Item << " ";
            crnt = crnt->Next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

This is the output:
[image]

My output should be something like:

```
===== Testing Step-1 =====
Testing default constructor...
List is empty.

Testing AddHead()...
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

Testing IsEmpty() and RemoveHead()...
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
List is empty.
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum example code. Currently there is a lot of junk lines that discourage.

Comment: In `IsEmpty()`, `Head==NULL;` You forgot the `if`. Just make it `return Head == NULL;`

Comment: Also, `RemoveHead()` is incomplete.

Comment: Whats wrong with RemoveHead() ??

Comment: @muzzi 1. It's missing a closing `}` and 2. it does not return a value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment by [Johnny Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp) :

Your `IsEmpty()` method should refactored from this:

```
bool LinkedList::IsEmpty()
{
  Head==NULL;
  return true;
}
```

To this:

```
bool LinkedList::IsEmpty()
{
  return Head==nullptr;
}
```

Thanks to [codekaizer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8012206/codekaizer) for pointing out using [nullptr instead of NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509734/null-vs-nullptr-why-was-it-replaced).