# Segmentation Fault wrt NULL pointers C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, null-pointer, josephus

I am trying to use a circular linked list to solve the Josephus problem. But in the create function I got a segmentation error regarding NULL pointer to the linked list node. Can anyone explain why there is a segmentation error? Thank You!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct llnode
{
    int data;
    bool life;
    struct llnode *ptr;
};
typedef struct llnode *llptr;
int create(llptr &L, llptr F, int n, int c=1)
{
    if(!L)
    {
        L = new(llnode);
        if(c=1)
        F = L;
        L->data = c;
        L->life = true;
        L->ptr = NULL;
    }
    if(c==n)
    {
        L->ptr = F;
        return 0;
    }
    create(L->ptr,F,n,1+c);
    return 0;
}
int execution(llptr L,int n)
{
    if(n==2)
    {
        cout<<"The Winner is: "<<L->data<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    L = L->ptr;
    while(L->life == false)
    L = L->ptr;
    L->life = false;
    while(L->life == false)
    L = L->ptr;
    execution(L,n-1);
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    llptr L,F;
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the Number of Players"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    create(L,F,n,1);
    execution(L,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're creating a list the "C-style" way. Is there a reason you don't build a `List` class to make it easier to guarantee that your `List` objects will always be in a good state?

Comment: I see an issue with `create` function, `create(L->ptr,F,n,1+c);` calling can be with `NULL` value as `L->ptr` you are setting above with `NULL`

Comment: As a matter of good coding practice always initialize your variables -- not just pointer varibless but *all* variables. `llptr L = nullptr; llptr F = nullptr; int n = 0;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is right here:

```
llptr L, F;
```

What are `L` and `F` pointing to? As of now, they're both Wild Pointers. That is, you have no guarantee. So when you pass them to `create()` and check `if(!L)`, it'll be false, since `L` is not nullptr.

So you'll then try to dereference `L` with `L->ptr = F;`. But again, `L` is pointing to some garbage address. This is Undefined Behavior.

Make sure to initialize all your pointers to `nullptr`.

Comment: Ohhh so just initialized pointers point to random locations... Alright! So initializing the pointers as nullptr in the main function should do the trick. Also a side question... what is the difference between L = NULL and L = nullptr (where L is a pointer btw)

Comment: @Ishan [NULL vs nullptr (Why was it replaced?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20509734/2602718)

Comment: Alright, will check it. And adding nullptr worked! Thanks a lot!