# Working of pass by reference for trees(struct) vs pass by reference for int

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, pass-by-reference

The following code is the function to "Delete Leaves With a Given Value(target)". Although I get what the code is doing, suppose I reach a leaf with target value and do `root=NULL`. Then, as it is passed by reference, won't all the roots it would return to become `NULL`? Like when we pass an int by reference, e.g., count and increment it, its value gets updated and remains the same even when the function returns to where it was called. So, why, in the below code, `root`'s value does not change?

```
 void helper(TreeNode* &root,int target){
        if(!root)return;
        
        helper(root->left,target);
        helper(root->right,target);
        if(root->val==target and root->left == NULL and root->right==NULL){
            root=NULL;
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, exactly as you wrote. But first you have 2 recursive calls to traverse left and right branches, and `root=NULL` is invoked only on the leaves.

Comment: Just removed [tag:c] from tags. Receiving by reference(`&`) is not yet supported in `C`. Although, `helper (TreeNode* &node, int target) {...}` seems more apt in this case.

Comment: @pptaszni leaves plus the nodes whose leaves were equal to the target and have been converted to NULL are also being deleted.

Comment: Please show a [mre] and show where you expect `root` to become null and how you know it isn't

Comment: @AlanBirtles sorry for not being clear. The question is https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-leaves-with-a-given-value/ and the example is in the page itself. Thanks

Comment: Please add the [mre] to the question, not in the comments and make sure it doesn't rely on external links which can die and make your question meaningless

Comment: `root` is a reference to a different pointer in every function call.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes of course, got it, thanks a million!

Comment: side note: for "modern" c++, use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`

Comment: @codeling will remember. is there a reason btw? thanks

Comment: @SnehaSharma `nullptr` is a new keyword explicitly for the purpose of an "empty" pointer. see e.g. [NULL vs nullptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509734/null-vs-nullptr-why-was-it-replaced) here on SO for more details.